# Are my Python libraries in the right place in my directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am having issue creating a standalone package with my Python script. I am using the latest version of python 3.8.3 in MacOS. My python script runs without issues through the terminal in the folder when my documents related to the programme are.

I have tried Pyinstaller, py2app (in a virtual environment) and now using Platypus.

Before I retry one of these again, I just wanted to check all my files / python libraries are installed in the correct place. Looking at my library all my files are in

```
Library > Frameworks > Python Framework > Versions > 3.8 > lib > python 3.8
```

[image: Library]

Are they in the right place or should they just be in the Framework folder at the top level of ^

Error message trying to package app on py2app was:

```
2020-08-15 10:18:02.399 FIBA[27366:3763263] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
```

Pyinstaller error was:

```
[30500] Error loading Python lib '/Users/adamsewell/Desktop/Python/Programmes/dist/EuroBasketApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/adamsewell/Desktop/Python/Programmes/dist/EuroBasketApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/adamsewell/Desktop/Python/Programmes/dist/EuroBasketApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/adamsewell/Desktop/Python/Programmes/dist/EuroBasketApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'
```

My questions are: are my extensions stored in the right place and is there a work around to the Pyinstaller error message, thank you